# Объясните как работает compare() в порядке возрастания и убывания

Tags: java, коллекции, compare

можете объяснить, пожалуйста как работает метод compare() в данном коде?

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class MyComp implements Comparator<String>{
    
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        String aStr, bStr;
        aStr = a;
        bStr = b;
        return bStr.compareTo(aStr);
    }
}


public class TreeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(new MyComp());
        ts.add("A");
        ts.add("C");
        ts.add("D");
        ts.add("B");
        
        for(String elem : ts) {
            System.out.print(elem + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        
    }
}
```

Почему если в методе `compare()` возвращать `return aStr.compareTo(bStr);` то коллекция будет сортироваться в порядке **возрастания**, а если `return bStr.compareTo(aStr);`, то в порядке **убывания**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что упрощено говоря aStr.compareTo(bStr) равно -bStr.compareTo(aStr). Т.е. если aStr.compareTo(bStr) возвращает 1, то bStr.compareTo(aStr) вернёт -1. Поэтому и сортировка производится в обратную сторону.

Пример на числах: допустим в функцию сравнения (не эту, но похожую) передается два числа a и b. Если функция возвращает 1, то мы первое число ставим перед вторым. Если же -1, то второе перед первым. В одном случае получится возрастающая сортировка, в другом убывающая.

Comment: Т.е., если у нас значение будет >0, то сортировка будет производиться в порядке возрастания, если же < 0 - то наоборот?

Comment: Вообще не совсем так, но для простоты пусть будет так.

Comment: Метод compareTo() уже и сравнивает, какая из строк "больше". А как этот результат дальше применяется из этого кода не видно.